# Not able to deserialize json string to list of wrapper

Tags: apex, lightning, community

What i am doing wrong

```
 public class filterPart{
    String type;
    String fieldAPI;
    String value;   

    public filterPart(String type, String fieldAPI, String value){
        this.type = type;
        this.fieldAPI = fieldAPI;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

    String s= ' [{"type":"12","fieldAPI":"contact","value":"abcd"},{"type":"12","fieldAPI":"contact","value":"abcd"}]';

    LIST<filterPart> pageErrors = new LIST<filterPart>();
    String s = '[{'type':'TECH_DisplayedErrorJSON__c'}]';
    pageErrors = (List<filterPart>) JSON.deserialize(s,List<filterPart>.class); 

    System.debug('pageErrors'+pageErrors);
```

Comment: Are you facing any errors or exception?

Comment: How you compiled this code part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this passing test you are doing nothing wrong in the code you posted:

```
@IsTest
private class MyTest {

    public class filterPart{
        String type;
        String fieldAPI;
        String value;   

        public filterPart(String type, String fieldAPI, String value){
            this.type = type;
            this.fieldAPI = fieldAPI;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    @IsTest
    static void test() {

        String s= ' [{"type":"12","fieldAPI":"contact","value":"abcd"},{"type":"12","fieldAPI":"contact","value":"abcd"}]';

        List<filterPart> fps = (List<filterPart>) JSON.deserialize(s, List<filterPart>.class);
        System.assertEquals(2, fps.size());
    }
}
```